# Why does providing an explicit initializer on an extern inside a function not override extern?

Tags: c++, extern

According to [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113), we can provide an initializer on a variable defined as extern, but doing so overrides the extern. An extern that has an initializer is a definition:

```
extern double pi = 3.1416; // definition
```

It is also stated in the book that providing an initializer on an extern inside a function is an error. These two statements together are a little confusing in my opinion and they give rise to the following questions in my mind:

If providing an initializer on an extern outside any function can override the extern, why can providing it on an extern inside a function not?

I also don't understand why someone would want to both obtain a declaration adding the extern keyword and provide an initializer. Is it not the same as defining a variable and providing an initializer on it? If it is not, why? Is the answer the reason why we cannot provide an initializer on an extern inside a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to C++ Primer, we can provide an initializer on a variable defined as `extern`, but doing so overrides the `extern`.

Only partially.

Providing an initializer forces the declaration to be a definition (except in the case of some static members of classes). It thus partially counteracts the effect of `extern`, which usually suppresses definition. However, `extern` can have other effects, and the initializer doesn't nullify those.

> It is also stated in the book that providing an initializer on an extern inside a function is an error.

Yes. At block scope, `extern` is used to force a declaration to have external or internal linkage (rather than declaring a local variable). However, the language prohibits *defining* such a variable in a local scope. You can only declare it there, and provide a matching definition at namespace scope. If you provide an initializer, then you're trying to define the variable there, which is not allowed.

> If providing an initializer on an extern outside any function can override the extern, why can providing it on an extern inside a function not?

As I explained, this premise is false. The initializer, in both cases, makes the declaration into a definition. In both cases, it does not override the fact that `extern` affects the *linkage* of the entity being declared.

> I also don't understand why someone would want to both obtain a declaration adding the `extern` keyword and provide an initializer. Is it not the same as defining a variable and providing an initializer on it? If it is not, why?

When we use `extern` together with an initializer, it is usually because we are trying to define a `const` object with external linkage. See below:

```
// At global scope:
const int c1 = 42;  // definition with internal linkage
extern const int c2;  // declaration with external linkage
extern const int c3 = 42;  // definition with external linkage
```